# activity is being destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, ondestroy

I just want to thank the people who answered my thread yesterday it helped me a lot but now the topic the different. I managed to fix the NPE but apparently my activity is being destroyed.

This is the logcat:

```
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1342)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at As2.packageTK.TicTacToeGame.changeLayout(TicTacToeGame.java:157)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at As2.packageTK.TicTacToeGame.checkTurn(TicTacToeGame.java:132)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at As2.packageTK.PlayerTurn1$1.onClick(PlayerTurn1.java:34)
03-26 06:55:27.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
```

These are the checkTurn() and changeLayout() located in my TicTacToeGame FragmentActivity class:

```
public class TicTacToeGame extends FragmentActivity{

    //fields..
    public int checkTurn()
    {
        if(turn == 1)
        {
            changeLayout(turn);
            turn = 2;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            changeLayout(turn);
            turn = 1;
            return 2;
        }
    }

    //changeLayout method
    public void changeLayout(int turn)
    {
        FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        FragmentTransaction ft;

        if(turn == 1) //if its player 1's turn
        {  
            if(fragment == null) //checks wether the current framelayout contains a fragment or not
            {   
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn1());
                ft.commit(); 
                //setPlayer1();
            }
            else
            {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn1());
                ft.commit();
                //setPlayer1();

            }
        }
        else
        {   
            if(fragment == null)
            {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();;
                ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn2());
                ft.commit(); 
                //setPlayer2();
            }
            else
            {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();;
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn2());
                ft.commit(); 
                //setPlayer2();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the onCreatedActivity and onCreateView of my fragments:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playerturn1, container, false);


        return view;
    }

        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            doneP1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doneP1);
            //resetP1 = (Button) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.resetP2);

            doneP1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                public void onClick(View v) {   
                    object.checkTurn();
                }
            });
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that problem is in 'onClick' method of 'Player1' class at line 34.

Comment: Line 34 is where my brackets end. Maybe I'm calling the object.checkTurn() wrong?

Comment: You can debug the code in onClick and get the proper insight for the issue, have you?

Comment: check out [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198702/error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568128/java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

Comment: It's chill I fixed it took me hours and code's working fine. I'm posting a new question and I'll post the solution later